# Error while installing Sitecore 9.2 - Unable to parse [variable('XConnectSolr_Core.Root')]

Tags: powershell, solr, sitecore

I'm setting a new installation of Sitecore 9.2 on a Windows Azure VM, I'm following the next tutorial: https://tothecore.sk/2019/07/22/sitecore-9-2-initial-release-installation-guide-for-development-machine/, but when I run the PowerShell script it gives me an error on the XconnetSolr_CleanCores: EnsurePath, I already checked the service and Solr service is running while I try to run the script but for some reason it stops when it arrives this step.

I already checked my SIF version, I currently have the 2.1.0 version installed, not duplicates. I followed all the steps and also I already tried to reinstalling Solr and SIF as starting a a clean installation, but I receive same result always.

The error that throws is the next one:

> [--------------------------------- XConnectSolr_CleanCores :
>   EnsurePath ----------------------------------------------]
>   Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Unable to parse
>   [variable('XConnectSolr_Core.Root')] - Exception calling "Evaluate"
>   with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the
>   preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set
>   to Stop: Unable to parse
>   [joinpath(variable('XConnectSolr_Solr.Server'),
>   variable('XConnectSolr_Xdb.Name'))] - Exception calling "Evaluate"
>   with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the
>   preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set
>   to Stop: Unable to parse
>   [joinpath(variable('XConnectSolr_Solr.FullRoot'), 'server', 'solr')] -
>   Exception calling "Evaluate" with "2" argument(s): "The running
>   command stopped because the preference variable
>   "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to
>   parse [resolvepath(parameter('XConnectSolr_SolrRoot'))] - Exception
>   calling "InvokeWithContext" with "2" argument(s): "The running command
>   stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or
>   common parameter is set to Stop: Cannot find path 'C:\Solr-7.5.0-920'
>   because it does not exist."""" At
>   C:\SitecoreInstallation\ResourceFiles\XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1:74
>   char:1
>   + Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Objec ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
>
> [TIME] 00:00:35 GetConfigFunctionResult : Unable to parse
>   [variable('XConnectSolr_Core.Root')] - Exception calling "Evaluate"
>   with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the
>   preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set
>   to Stop: Unable to parse
>   [joinpath(variable('XConnectSolr_Solr.Server'),
>   variable('XConnectSolr_Xdb.Name'))] - Exception calling "Evaluate"
>   with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the
>   preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set
>   to Stop: Unable to parse
>   [joinpath(variable('XConnectSolr_Solr.FullRoot'), 'server', 'solr')] -
>   Exception calling "Evaluate" with "2" argument(s): "The running
>   command stopped because the preference variable
>   "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to
>   parse [resolvepath(parameter('XConnectSolr_SolrRoot'))] - Exception
>   calling "InvokeWithContext" with "2" argument(s): "The running command
>   stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or
>   common parameter is set to Stop: Cannot find path 'C:\Solr-7.5.0-920'
>   because it does not exist."""" At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.1.0\Private\JsonConfiguration.ps1:226
>   char:20
>   + ...      return GetConfigFunctionResult -FunctionText $InputObject -Param ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,GetConfigFunctionResult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: **Cannot find path 'C:\Solr-7.5.0-920' because it does not exist.**"""" At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.1.0\Private\JsonConfiguration.ps1:226 char:20

It's looking for the directory C:\Solr-7.5.0-920 and not finding it. I did a quick google search to see if I could figure out what this might be and found [Apache Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

As this relates to the specific installation script you are using, I would advise reaching out to a product specific community for more in-depth support.

Comment: Good catch, actually I had the wrong path on my PowerShell script variable, that was the reason why it wasn't finding that place. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is also still applicable for Sitecore 10.2 when you are running the `XP1.SingleDeveloper.ps1` powershell script.

Ensure that the `$SolarRoot` is correctly mapped.

[image]